# Android Market Search with "LIKE" clause on Package Name

Tags: android, google-play

Is there a way to search the Android Market with a LIKE clause on the package name?

Example: I want to seach for all apps that start with package name "com.example"

Comment: [From the official dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#PerformingSearch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

https://market.android.com/search?q=com.example

Comment: That's all/some packages which contain "com.example", but not all start with that.

Comment: This does seem to work. Example: https://market.android.com/search?q=com.google.android.apps

Comment: Yep. It does work but as @alextsc mentions, it's not perfect. You can get a few that might not quite match.

Answer (score 0):

Not really with a LIKE clause, you need the correct subpackage name.

For example searching for "com.navigon" would provide all Apps by Navigon, anyhow this is not their full package name as searching for "com.navigon.navigator_select" only provides Navigon Select Apps.

Hope this is what you are searching for.

Afaik, "com.navi*" or wildcards does not work.